# Difference between su oracle and su - oracle?

Tags: unix

Simple question, what is the difference between

`su oracle` and `su - oracle`

I am not sure what is the significance of `-` in both the commands.

**Update:**

After doing su oracle, tried which sqlplus but it was not identified but by doing `su - oracle`, sqlplus environment was set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the man page

```
 -l      Simulate a full login.  The environment is discarded except for HOME, SHELL, PATH, TERM, and USER.  HOME and SHELL are modified as above.
         USER is set to the target login.  PATH is set to ``/bin:/usr/bin''.  TERM is imported from your current environment.  The invoked shell is
         the target login's, and su will change directory to the target login's home directory.

 -       (no letter) The same as -l.
```

In a nutshell, if you use `su - oracle` you switch to the user `oracle` and the environment is reset. Without `-`, the environment is not reset.

For example, without `-` :

```
#(root) export HELLO=world
#(root) su postgres
$(postgres) echo $HELLO
world
$(postgres)
```

And with `-` :

```
#(root) export HELLO=world
#(root) su - postgres
$(postgres) echo $HELLO

$(postgres)
```

Answer (score 0):

`su - oracle` it starts a login shell so the oracle user environment is used. W/O the hyphen just changes to the user oracle user; this grants the same rights as the oracle user so you can have access to files/directories owned by oracle.